# Need help with calculation SPI Frequency

Tags: spi

I am using Bit banging SPI to communicate with SDCard. I am using QCA4020 and I have no information regarding the Pin Toggling Frequency. To get the max speed of SPI Possible with the hardware I am generating clock by setting and resetting pin w/o any sort of delay in between.

I am taking the time before starting the communication and after ending the communication of 512 Bytes, and getting around 25600 Bytes per second from that calculation. I have to put down on paper a rough SPI Frequency that I am using for the communication and I have no tool to do it atm.

My calculations are

25600 Bytes per second ,

hence 25600*8 bits per second,

1 Bit change = 2 edge and hence 1 Clock.

therefore my speed comes to around 25600*8 = 204800 Hz.

Does that sound correct or do you suggest any other method to do so?

2) How is one supposed to get Bytes per second using the Pin Toggling Frequency?

My assumptions are :

Pin Toggling Frequency : 400000.
Hence Bytes per second will be 400000/8 = 50000.

Is it correct? or Am I missing something?

[Does this hold true in terms of bitbanging as well?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122500/spi-communication-bits-per-second-vs-hz?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct (sort of), but this is not a good way to do SPI given you have a feature packed microcontroller. You should use the SPI module on your microcontroller - this will generate all the signals and protocol correctly. You've missed that you also need to update the data at each clock tick. So (depending on the SPI phase), it will be more like: clock down > change data > clock up.

Having a toggling pin is not optimal for a couple of reasons:

1. You also need to update your data, so just toggling the pin tends to give uneven mark/space.
2. Any interrupts that happen will stop transmission.

Bit-banging is great if you have a low-power microcontroller without proper hardware, and just want something quick and easy. It's a fun exercise to write your own reusable code for such situations, but these days even the lowest end micros come with hardware SPI (it's essentially just a shift register).

Comment: Ah! Somebody made a mistake reading documents and gave me SD card interface on SPI Line that can be only configured for SPI Slave configuration. Plus I don't have freedom to work with low level register and can only use Manufacturer provided Abstraction API. Therefore the trouble.

Comment: I don't recommend Bit banging SPI , because of its modes and speeds of communication. use Manufacturer provided API.

Comment: @user19579 Agreed, but you can if you're in a corner! SPI is a pain because it's not a proper standard.

Comment: Even done properly with hardware SPI, SPI mode is not great for SD cards (ie. is very slow).